# Anyone had success mocking HttpRequests with Robolectric?

Tags: android, http, testing, mocking

I'm just starting with Robolectric.  It seems to be working fine to mock most Android classes but when my class under test tries to create a DefaultHttpClient() it gets the dreaded "Stub!" error.

The class under test fails at this line:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

even though the article at http://robolectric.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-test-http-requests.html?showComment=1297722651278#c3540420071421225744 seems to suggest this should just work.

My test looks like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
  Robolectric.addPendingHttpResponse(200, "OK");
  service = new CheckinService();
}

@Test
public void testIt() throws IOException
{
  // Fails at HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient()
  service.doStuff(Robolectric.application,
                  REG_ID,
                  TEST_DOMAIN);
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it within eclipse.
Took me a while to figure out how to fix that but here it is:
Go to your test project preferences > build path > order&export > select robolectric jar and press move to top.

Comment: That sounds like what I needed.

Comment: This method solves tons of seemingly random problems in Eclipse + ADT. I didn't think to use it here!

Comment: Be aware that if you are using a newer version of the android-support-library than robolectric, you'll need to make sure that goes above robolectric in the build path.

Comment: With IntelliJ/Android Studio and Maven, I had to move the Android platform beneath _all_ of the Maven dependencies, not just Robolectric.

Answer (score 3):

In your pom.xml move the robolectric dependency on top of the android one.

Comment: I'm not using maven so I'm not sure how to replicate that without it.  Any ideas?