# Mock HttpResponse with Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric, mockwebserver

Using Robolectric 2.3-SNAPSHOT, I want to test an object that'll execute a request in the background. In order to isolate it, I'm trying to mock the HttpResponse returned, without success after some hours invested.

I've created a project that anyone can clone. Simly run *./gradlew check* https://github.com/Maragues/RobolectricDummyProject (git clone https://github.com/Maragues/RobolectricDummyProject.git)

I've tried

- Robolectric.setDefaultHttpResponse(200, "my_mocked_word");
- MockWebServer (https://code.google.com/p/mockwebserver/)

But the tests fail because they query the real URL

```
  private static final String MOCKED_WORD = "MOCKED";

  @Test
  public void mockedRequestUsingMockServer() throws Exception {
    mMockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody(MOCKED_WORD));
    mMockWebServer.play();

    Robolectric.getFakeHttpLayer().interceptHttpRequests(false);
    Robolectric.getFakeHttpLayer().interceptResponseContent(false);

    String result = request.loadDataFromNetwork();

    assertEquals(MOCKED_WORD, result);
  }

  @Test
  public void mockedRequestUsingRobolectric() throws Exception {
    Robolectric.setDefaultHttpResponse(200, MOCKED_WORD);

    String result = request.loadDataFromNetwork();

    assertEquals(MOCKED_WORD, result);
  }
```

The code executing the request

```
public String loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    // With Uri.Builder class we can build our url is a safe manner
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse("http://robospice-sample.appspot.com/reverse").buildUpon();
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("word", word);

    String url = uriBuilder.build().toString();

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
      .openConnection();
    String result = IOUtils.toString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    urlConnection.disconnect();

    return result;
  }
```

Possibly related questions

- [Can't capture HTTP request with robolectric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708844/cant-capture-http-request-with-robolectric) (I've tried that without success. Perhaps I'm missing something)
- [Anyone had success mocking HttpRequests with Robolectric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998176/anyone-had-success-mocking-httprequests-with-robolectric) (I'm not using eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Robolectric's [FakeHttpLayer](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/tester/org/apache/http/FakeHttpLayer.java) only works with Apache's HttpClient, which is highly discouraged on versions greater than Froyo. Extracted from [Robolectric's Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robolectric/0wZxGivxsuE/ZVpvuPZdUeoJ)

*That being said, the usage of HttpUrlConnection will cause you trouble. I'd try to use Android's implementation of HttpClient where possible, since Robolectric intercepts all calls to that library and lets you set up canned responses to your HTTP calls. We're looking at doing the same for HttpUrlConnection, though it's not clear when that'll happen.*

Apart from that, a unit test should not need to mock the HTTP layer. My approach was wrong from the beginning.

Comment: Why should a Unit Test not mock the http layer, it is a external dependency which might introduce some unknown and flickery results how would you else secure specific results?

Comment: I also want to know why you should not mock a HTTP layer. Could you please explain. What is the right approach?

Answer (score 5):

You're disabling Roboelectric's HTTP layer, so you're using the real HTTP layer.  This means that there's no clever magic happening under the hood of your test: when you send an HTTP request, it's really going out onto the internet (as you are seeing).

MockWebServer doesn't stop this.  It just sets up a web server locally, that your test can connect to.

So to resolve this problem, you need to stop attempting to connect to a real server, and instead, connect to the mock server.  To do this, yo need to inject/set the URL in the request.

```
@Test
  public void mockedRequestUsingMockServer() throws Exception {
    mMockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
    mMockWebServer.play();
    mMockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody(MOCKED_WORD));

    request.myUrl = mMockWebServer.getUrl("/");

    String result = request.loadDataFromNetwork();

    assertEquals(MOCKED_WORD, result);
    mMockWebServer.shutdown();
  }
```

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction regarding the use of MockWebServer, which I was using wrong. Here's an example of a correct use http://codrspace.com/bsphere/unit-testing-android-http-connections/ Robolectric's issue is of a different nature, tho. Thanks!

Comment: Just did so. Thanks for your interest. Because your answer is the only one that does actually help to mock http requests, i'll award the bounty to you. I hope that you don't mind my edit, but your instructions wheren't right.

Comment: Absolutely, the point is to make the answers useful for future readers.  Thanks for updating it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this(ref:https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver).

```
  // Create a MockWebServer. These are lean enough that you can create a new
    // instance for every unit test.
    MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
    // Schedule some responses.
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("it's all cool"));
    // Start the server.
    server.play();
    // Ask the server for its URL. You'll need this to make HTTP requests.
    //Http is my own http executor.
    Http.Response response = http.get(server.getUrl("/"));
```

then, you can compare the response to `server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("it's all cool"));`

MockWebServer is a part of okhttp  https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver. the URLConnectionImpl in android 4.4 have been [changed from defaultHttpClient to Okhttp](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/54970/2/luni/src/main/java/java/net/URL.java).

Comment: What do I have to add as a dependency in gradle in order to use `MockResponse`?